# How to get the scale factor of dwm for a non-dpi-aware process?

Tags: c++, winapi, dwm, dpi-aware

Size and position of a control are modified by windows (dwm). I need a way to get the exact scaling in x and y to counter-balance this.

I can not use a manifest, because I am writing a plugin to an `.exe`  (3ds Max). 
I can not change the manifest of 3dsMax ( I am not Autodesk. I can not call `setprocessdpiawareness()` , again because I am a plugin (dll)
into another `exe` and I would kill layout of my parent process.

The solution should work in windows 7, 8, 10. So i can not use calls that had been introduced in 10 or 8.1

I already tried:

```
LogicalToPhysicalPoint(0,& p1);

PhysicalToLogicalPoint(0, &p2);
```

This doesnt change anything (POINTS are unchanged).  I do use old school C++ and common controls (subclassing). No WPF, again because I cant use WPF as it doesnt run with my parent exe.

```
HWND hw = CreateWindowEx(0, L"STATIC", L"thumbnails",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_WHITEFRAME | SS_BITMAP ,
        9*2, 64*2, 90*2, 46*2,  hParentDialog, 0, 0, 0);
```

After adding the magic "2*" to the controls size and position I do get it where I want. But this is a hack that only works on my current machine with the current monitor.

I would like to replace "2" with the multiplier that dwm applies.

Comment: You have this backwards.  If the host app would not be dpiAware then you wouldn't have to compensate for DPI by multiplying by 2, the DPI virtualization feature would already do that.  And 3dsMax can certainly be expected to be dpiAware.  So all you have to do is obtain the DPI of the display and divide by 96 to get the multiplier.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way for a non-dpi aware app to get the true DPI setting of a monitor. One way would be to use a separate process that is marked as DPI aware to return the true values to your plugin.

Comment: What version of 3dsmax? This issue may have already been addressed in  3dsmax 2017.